# Docker Moodle localhost not working (CentOS)

Tags: docker, apache, centos7, moodle, simplesamlphp

I have to work with Moodle, so I installed Moodle from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/jauer/moodle

I created the docker containers.

MySQL container:

```
docker run -d --name DB -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=moodle -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=moodle -e MYSQL_USER=moodle -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=moodle mysql
```

Moodle container:

```
docker run -d -P --name moodle --link DB:DB -e MOODLE_URL=http://localhost:8081 -p 8081:80 jhardison/moodle
```

Result after docker ps -a:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS                                                                              NAMES
647128e9d155   jhardison/moodle   "/etc/apache2/foregr…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes               0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp, :::8081->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49157->443/tcp, :::49157->443/tcp   moodle

e83ad7433905   mysql              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes               0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                               DB
```

I open http://localhost:8081 but nothing is showing. Message: Can't connect.
Also http://localhost:8080 is a white webpage. It loads but without content.

My Apache version:

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 16 2020 16:18:20
```

I have a Windows host machine and I am connecting via ssh to a CentOS VM. I have also installed SimpleSAMLphp in the VM, and I can access to it from Windows at https://localhost:8443/simplesaml/module.php

I need to make Moodle work. I have read forum topics, tried different ways to install Moodle but still can't achieve what I want. It must be installed in CentOS.

Thanks in advance and I hope you could help me.

Comment: I have run the two docker commands you've listed and I get a Moodle page when I go to `localhost:8081`.

Comment: did you try that in Ubuntu or CentOS

Comment: I tried it on Windows 10 with WSL2. I don't have access to a CentOS machine, unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

I think you should go with bitnami moodle image as they have all the latest release and they have also documented the installation process pretty well

`https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/moodle/`